# Why is composer not able to autoload files from my /src folder on production server

Tags: php, composer-php, require, autoload

On my local environment everything works fine, but on my production server files from my `/src` folder are not autoloaded by composer. I get the following error:

> Warning: require(/home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/example-plugin/vendor/composer/../../src/Commands/Example_Commands.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/example-plugin/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 55

The file really exists (I checked it multiple times), but it looks like production cannot require a path like:

> /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/example-plugin/vendor/composer/../../src/Commands/Example_Commands.php

But only:

> /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/example-plugin/src/Commands/Example_Commands.php

On my local environment I removed already my `/vendor` folder and `composer.lock` file and ran the following commands:

`> composer dump-autoload`

and

`> composer install --no-dev`

My project folder looks like this:

```
resources
src
- Commands
  - Example_Commands.php
- Other_Class.php
- Another_Class.php
vendor
- composer
  - ..other composer files
  - autoload_real.php
- ..other packages
composer.json
composer.lock
plugin-index.php
```

My composer.json looks like this:

```
{
  "require": {
    "illuminate/encryption": "^9.33",
    "wp-cli/wp-config-transformer": "^1.3",
    "azurre/php-simple-logger": "^1.1"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "src/User.php",
      "src/Utils.php",
      "src/Config_Checker.php",
      "src/Admin_Notices.php",
      "src/ACF.php",
      "src/Commands/Example_Commands.php",
      "src/Service_Logic.php",
      "src/Cron.php",
      "src/Email.php"
    ]
  }
}
```

In my plugin-index.php (the first file loaded) I start autoloading like this:

`require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'vendor/autoload.php');`

To be clear; I ran the composer commands on my local machine and uploaded the project to the production server.

Comment: You should switch to this https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload `psr-0/4` or `classmap`. `files` will be *always* included at the start and that not needed for classes (only good for files with global functions). If your project gets bigger, in every request you load a bunch of files that maybe not needed in that request.

Comment: @Foobar thanks, do need composer installed on production server for this?

Comment: Not for *this*: switching from `files` to other autoload. But normaly you should have composer on the server. Normaly you exclude the `vendor` folder in `./gitignore` and only upload the `composer.lock`  and then do `composer install --no-dev` and `composer dump-autoload` on the production server. I dont now how you upload your project, but you should do the steps above on the server. Sometimes the root folder of your project is different in production, then uploading the `autload.php` from local will not work. So exclude `vendor` completly while uploading and generate it on the server.

Comment: Yes, that is how I normally do this, but in this case, I create a plugin that has to be installed on multiple machines where I do not know if they have composer installed.

Comment: Then write your own autloader for your classes. Round about 10 Lines of code. Since you have no namespaces in your classes, that should be easy.

Comment: Currently its hard to see where the problem is.

Comment: @Robert: Composer does not need to be available on hosts, just provide the vendor folder content, it contains a `vendor/autoload.php` you can include to have the (composer) configured autoload setup. Then package your application with the vendor folder and you have an artifact that does not depend on specific tools but only the PHP platform. Keep the packaging near to yourself. Version control the build.